# Wait Ajax finish to do other function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am updating some values in my page using Ajax. And then, after is finishes I need to do other function, using that values.

I am putting one function after the other, but even in that way the second function is not waiting the Ajax to finish.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".data").blur(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var value = $(this).html();
        var ad = id.split(';');

        Update(valor, id);
        Function2(ad[1]);


    });
});


function Update(value, id){
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
           // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
           xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
         } else { // code for IE6, IE5
           xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
         }
         xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
           if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
             document.getElementById("div_table").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
           }
         }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","update.php?value="+value+"&id="+id,true);
        xmlhttp.send();

}


function Function2(ad){
    var name_1 = $("#name_1").html(); //This part is updated inside a <span> by the Ajax function
    $('#'+ad).html(name_1);  
}
```

Comment: Call your function2 from your onreadystatechange-handler.

Comment: ajax has a property of async. when set to true it will execute first and will not let any other function run until it finishes

Comment: @Saechel No, you got that wrong. The XMLHttpRequest constructor has an async parameter that defaults to true, making the request asynchronous = will not wait. If you set it to false you get an synchronous request = will wait (and block everything else, and therefore not recommended)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually really simple with jQuery Ajax.

```
$.ajax({
    url:"data/retrieve",
    success:function(result){
       //call your function
       Function2(result);
 }});
```

Have a look at jQuery Ajax documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

**Edit**: Since you're using GET as your request type, why not use jQuery.get? Here, you can use this code. Simple and clean.

Also, don't forget to mark this as the answer if it works for you. We don't want answer-less questions here at StackOverflow, do we?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".data").blur(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var value = $(this).html();
        var ad = id.split(';');

        Update(value, id); 
    });
});


function Update(value, id){
    $.get("update.php", {value: value, id: id}, function (data) {
         //call your function
         Function2(data);
    });
}


function Function2(ad){
    var name_1 = $("#name_1").html(); //This part is updated inside a <span> by the Ajax function
    $('#'+ad).html(name_1);  
}
```

Comment: OP seems to be using jQuery so this would be the best solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @abdhoms. Just one think, in my page I am getting the result from the page update.php and putting it inside a div with the ID #div_table. How can I do that using JQuery.get?

Comment: Hi @user3697768, it's the same approach. Here's a sample code:
$.get("update.php", {key: value, function (result) {
         //display the result in a div
         $("#div_table").html(result);
    });

Answer (score 2):

You have to call `function2` inside the handler function, that is inside the function that you assign to `onreadystatechange`.

In addition, I suggest to use jQuery to make you ajax calls, since its API its a lot simpler and cross-browser. See the documentation of `jQuery.ajax()` for some examples: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks Claudio. I am trying to understand the Jquery.ajax so I can use it, but in my page I am getting the result from the page update.php and putting it inside a div with the ID #div_table. How can I do that using JQuery.get?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I usually use is an ajax function with a return statement

```
        function ajax_func(value,id)
        {
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                AJAX=new XMLHttpRequest(); 
            else
                AJAX=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            if (AJAX)
            {
                AJAX.open("GETT", "update.php", false);
                AJAX.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                AJAX.send("value="+value+"&id="+id);
                return AJAX.responseText;                                         
            } 
            else
                return null;
        }
```

All you need to do is to get the result and execute your other function

```
var Result = ajax_func("value","id");
new_func();
```