# How do I use a jQuery function like $.getJSON() within a normal JS function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a method like this

```
            var getStatus = function (tr, startTime, endTime) {
                var toReturn ="";
                    $.getJSON('../java_output/bugs.json', function (dataOuter) {
                        //random code here//
                        //code causes changes to 'toReturn'

                    });
                return (toReturn);
            }
```

Basically, I call `getStatus` and get a return value, which depends on the getJSON file. However, because it's a callback method, I don't get the current version of `toReturn`, and instead, get `""` as the value because that's how it was initialized.

Comment: Use jQuery deferred...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a callback!

```
var getStatus = function (tr, startTime, endTime, callback) {
    var toReturn = "";
    $.getJSON('../java_output/bugs.json', function (dataOuter) {
        //changes..
        callback(toReturn);
    });
}
```

Then call it!

```
getStatus(tr, start, end, function(data) {
    //your toReturn value;
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, could you tell me how exactly the callback works? I'm not very familiar with it. I tried to get the value and return it, but when I get the returned value, it still comes up as undefined.

Comment: I mean it partially works, but the problem is, I'm using this to add columns to an HTML table. When running this code, instead of adding the column to each row iteratively, it adds EVERY single column to the last row.

Answer (score 2):

This is because `$.getJSON` is an asynchronous call. I think that you have few choices:

1. Use a sleep to wait until you get the response, and then return it. This will obviously hang the browser until you get the response or an error. Not a good choice...
2. Make `getStatus` an asynchonous function. So let it accept a callback function, and pass it to `$.getJSON`, or call it inside the callback function passed to `$.getJSON`.
3. Use the Deferred Object pattern. jQuery provides it: http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/. Basically you return a "promise" object. The client can attach handlers to this object, to execute code when the promise is "resolved" or "rejected". In the handler function of `$.getJSON` you can resolve the promise, passing also the response, or reject it in case of error.

See also this question, it's a similar case: [Wait Ajax finish to do other function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25129167/wait-ajax-finish-to-do-other-function)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
        var getStatus = function (tr, startTime, endTime) {
            toReturn = new $.Deferred();
            $.getJSON("../java_output/bugs.json"
            , function (dataOuter) {
                //random code here//
                //code causes changes to 'toReturn'

                toReturn.resolve(dataOuter);
            });
            return toReturn.promise();
        };
        $.when(getStatus())
            .done(function (_toReturn) {
            // do stuff with `_toReturn` 
            console.log(_toReturn);
        });
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/355Pw/